# Qt: KeyPressEvent While Dragging an item from a listView

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, keypress

I have a situation where i need to handle the KeyPress when dragging an item from the listView to my Widget. I have overridden the **KeyPressEvent()** function in my listView but while dragging an item and pressing any key, does not fire the keyPressEvent. But, if i press "escape" key on the keyboard the QDrag image ior pixmap disappears. I need to handle **keyPressEvent()**  when an item is dragged

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Just a hint. If you are Windows-user, note that if you use QDrag->exec() 
on Windows, the Qt event loop is blocked during the operation. On other systems this should work.

Comment: Try QApplication::processEvents() sometimes (for exemple, by timer-ticks) while dragging.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I'll try QApplication::processEvents().